# Open a screen when firebase notification received in flutter while app is background or terminated

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, notifications, dart-null-safety

want to create a screen that launch when a firebase notification is received while the app is in the background or terminated in flutter (like package callKeep ).please anyone help me create that.

Answer (score -2):

You just need to handle its background handler method it will works.You need to initialize this method in main() method.

```
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  debugPrint(message.toString());
  debugPrint(message.data.toString());
  debugPrint(message.notification!.title);
}
 FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
```

Comment: it is not launching the screen when app is closed or terminated